# Firebase with classic data structures

Tags: data-structures, redis, firebase

Firebase allows you to store data in remote JSON tree and it can be nested up to 32 levels.
It's cool, but is there any way (or service) to store your data in **lists, sets or hashes** like Redis does, but **remotely**, like Firebase does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list is a collection of ordered data? If so: see Firebase's documentation on [saving lists of data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push). If you're used to arrays, you might want to read these two blog posts on [arrays in Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and [real-time synchronized arrays](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-05-06-synchronized-arrays.html) too.

In JSON (and thus in Firebase) any associative array is essentially a set: you can associate one value with each key. So I'd map sets to regular [Firebase `set` operations](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-set).

As you may see: there are quite some links to the Firebase guide in the above.

Comment: Thanks, i agree Firebase deserves a deeper look